# XmlDocument class is removing formatting, c#, .NET

Tags: c#, formatting, save, xmldocument

i was wondering if anyone knows how to stop xmldocument.Save() from reformatting the document.

Its not that the document is not formatted correctly with respect to XML, the particular document i am working with has lots of white space and things like that which - upon save - is all being removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the [PreserveWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property to `true` before you save the document.

Answer (score 0):

set PreserveWhiteSpace to true