# Preserve xml formatting using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, formatting, xmldocument

I am using XmlDocument to work with xml

How do I save my "XmlDocument" with my current formatting?

Current formatting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>

  <element></element>

</root>
```

Code:

```
                XmlDocument testDoc = new XmlDocument();
                testDoc.Load(@"C:\Test.xml");

                **(do reading/writing using only XmlDocument methods)**

                testDoc.Save(@"C:\Test.xml");
```

There is a similar topic:
[XmlDocument class is removing formatting, c#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684253/xmldocument-class-is-removing-formatting-c-net)

The accepted answer is PreserveWhiteSpace = true, which in reality removes all whitespaces instead of preserving them.

**Example:**

Code:

```
    XmlDocument testDoc = new XmlDocument();
    testDoc.Load(@"C:\Test.xml");
    testDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    testDoc.Save(@"C:\Test.xml");
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><element></element></root>
```

Comment: `PreserveWhiteSpace = true, which in reality removes all whitespaces instead of preserving them`.. Are you sure? MSDN Says `If PreserveWhitespace is true before Load or LoadXml is called, white space nodes are preserved; otherwise, if this property is false, significant white space is preserved, white space is not.`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was preserving them after loading

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting `PreserveWhitespace` to true works for me - but you've got to do it *before loading* so that the whitespace doesn't get thrown away at load time:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        XmlDocument testDoc = new XmlDocument();
        testDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        testDoc.Load("Test.xml");
        testDoc.Save("Output.xml");
    }
}
```

I've just tried that, and the whitespace was preserved.

Comment: same here. Maybe it's something he's doing in between?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was preserving them after loading

Comment: Mind that `PreserveWhitespace` preserves only elements indentation. If you have attributes in new lines or multiline values they will be reformatted.

Comment: @raj Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Umm. I'm seeing whitespace being preserved when using `PreserveWhiteSpace=true`. Perhaps it was `false` when you loaded?

```
var xmlStr = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<root>

  <element></element>

</root>";

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
xmlDoc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>

  <element></element>

</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was preserving them after loading

Comment: Thank you for teaching me two new things:  
1st: literal escape ""  
2nd: how to use `Console.Out` in a nifty way

Answer (score 1):

use preservewhitespace before you load. It will keep formatting same

```
like above
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

if you will use it after loading. it will kill white spaces in between

Comment: This adds nothing beyond what was already presented in the answers from 2 years ago.