# How to add XML nodes without losing original structure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have code where i add new Nodes to a xml file and it works perfect, but have an issue, the original structure of the xml file is changed when i save the changes on the add.

Originally the file has a full line or row to each node like this:

```
<DATA>
   <ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170300"/><wn v = "00Y6354"/><bn v = ""/></ROW>
   <ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170301"/><wn v = "00Y6355"/><bn v = ""/></ROW>
   <ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170302"/><wn v = "00Y6356"/><bn v = ""/></ROW>
</DATA>
```

but after adding new nodes and saving changes, structure looks like this:

```
<DATA>
   <ROW>
      <mk v = "2801"/>
      <gd v = "170300"/>
      <wn v = "00Y6354"/>
      <bn v = ""/>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <mk v = "2801"/>
      <gd v = "170301"/>
      <wn v = "00Y6355"/>
      <bn v = ""/>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <mk v = "2801"/>
      <gd v = "170302"/>
      <wn v = "00Y6356"/>
      <bn v = ""/>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <mk v = "2341"/>
      <gd v = "170342"/>
      <wn v = "00Y9872"/>
      <bn v = "new node"/>
   </ROW>
</DATA>
```

I've tried to find some examples with the FINAL OUTPUT like the first structure, but nothing. So it is possible to save the changes without changing the original structure somebody tell me please!

My code is like this:

```
    public void CreateXML(string[] ipRow, string ipFile)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(ipFile);

        for (int j = 0; j < ipRow.Length; j++)
        {
            doc.LoadXml(ipRow[j]);
            XmlNode newNode = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode copiedNode = xmlDoc.ImportNode(newNode, true);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(copiedNode);                
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(ipFile);
    }
```

I just want to apply some kind of format, or at least indicate the program to respect original structure of what is already inside of the file. 
I've found forums where they say that you can use StringBuilders, XmlWriterSettings, and stuff, but doesn't work, and as you can see, the new node comes from a string, so, i can't change the way the new node is created, the code must be kept as is, and just add the rules to keep the original format.

Or if somebody knows that it's impossible to do this with C# on Visual Studio 2008 just tell me (i'll only trust in apparent expert users).

Please reply! thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589592/preserve-xml-formatting-using-xmldocument

Comment: i've already tried that thing of preservewhitespace, and it' doesnt works, the result of that is someting like this: 

<DATA><ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170300"/><wn v = "00Y6354"/><bn v = ""/></ROW><ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170301"/><wn v = "00Y6355"/><bn v = ""/></ROW><ROW><mk v = "2801"/><gd v = "170302"/><wn v = "00Y6356"/><bn v = ""/></ROW></DATA>


ONLY ONE ROW FOR ALL THE XML CODE, i'm not looking for that

Comment: Why do you need this particular format? It's quite unusual for the formatting to be significant in an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of repeating what you may have been told elsewhere, you cannot do this simply by saving your XmlDocument. You can try using an XmlTextWriter:

```
using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
  xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.None;
  yourDocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
}
```

... but I'm not sure if that will give you the very specific layout you are looking for.

Or you can get the whole document as a string (using yourDocument.OuterXml) and then use normal string matching (REGEX are probably best) to remove all the carriage returns, except those before and after the `<ROW>` nodes.

Bear in mind that none of this makes any actual difference to the structure of your file - it's just a case of formatting.